# Copy return values of qsort pointer in c

Tags: c

I have an char array of four names and intend to sort them with qsort as follows:

```
char players[4][20];
char *strings[4];

/*input of the players into players[4] via stdin not shown*/

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    strings[i] = players[i];
    printf("strings unsorted: %s \n", strings[i]);
}

size_t strings_len = sizeof(strings) / sizeof(char *);
qsort(strings, strings_len, sizeof(char *),cstring_cmp);
```

Qsort returns now a pointer with the sorted names. How can I copy the name into a new char array namesSorted[4][20]?

Cheers, Judith

Comment: Any particular reason you're not just sorting them in-place in `players`? There are legitimate reasons, to be sure; only curious if one was among your reasons.

Comment: Yes, it the pointer "strings" is pointing to players and if I change the first array of players (players[0]), that the but the third pointer of string is pointing to it, then I also change the value of the third point!? Does this make sense?

Comment: Forgive me for not following that. What I was asking was is there a reason you didn't just sort `players[4][20]` directly. you can easily with the right comparator, since each each item (in this case each "row") is 20 chars wide. Doesn't matter. NPE's answer below will likely solve your issue.

Comment: Can you please provide a code snippet? Thank you! Judith

Answer (score 1):

```
char namesSorted[4][20];
...
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    strcpy(namesSorted[i], strings[i]);
}
```

> [U]nfortunately, I get some entries more than once after using `strcpy`.

I suspect that your comparison function (which is not included in the question) is flawed.

Comment: That is how I have tried it. But unfortunately, I get some entries more than once after using strcpy. Especially if I start the program the second time. Do I have to clear all arrays before I can use them? Memset did not help either.

Comment: @JM-dk: If you get the same entry more than once, then your comparison function is probably flawed.

Comment: I use the standard qsort from stdio.h or stdlib.h and do not perform a comparison.

Comment: @JM-dk NPE is referring to `cstring_cmp`.

Comment: `int cstring_cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {

    const char **ia = (const char **)a;

    const char **ib = (const char **)b;

    return strcmp(*ia, *ib); 

}`

Comment: Thank you very much all. It helped me to find the mistake. A missing `memset` was the cause. But more importantly I wrote the sorted string back into the original array within the same `for` loop. Therefore I changed the source of the pointer `strings` before I grabbed the entire sorted result. Cheers to all, Judith